# Finding average of nested list in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, average, nested-lists

ive been struggling to the the average of a nested list and this is what i have at the moment:

```
(defun nested-average2 (tree &optional (sum 0) (count 0))
  (cond ((null tree)
         (/ sum count))
        ((listp (first tree))
         (nested-average2 (rest tree)
                          (nested-average2 (first tree) sum)
                          (incf count)))
        (t
         (nested-average2 (rest tree)
                          (+ sum (first tree))
                          (incf count)))))
```

However it returns non whole number

For example, using this `(nested-average2 ' (10 ((30 1) 20) (8 (5 (50 7)) 9) 40))`, it returns 2425/192 when it should return 18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works for ordinary lists, but not for sublists.

- One of the problems is that when you recurse on a sublist, you increment count by *one* only, not by the number of elements that have been processed.
- The other being that in that case you already compute a 'sub-average' which you add to the sum.

The easiest way to do this is to just compute the sum and the count until you're done with the whole tree; only then should you do the final division to compute the average, such as:

```
(defun nested-average (sxp)
  (labels
      ((sub (sxp tot cnt)
         (cond
          ((null sxp)  (values tot cnt))
          ((consp sxp) (multiple-value-bind (tot1 cnt1) (sub (car sxp) tot cnt)
                         (sub (cdr sxp) tot1 cnt1)))
          (t           (values (+ tot sxp) (1+ cnt))))))
    (multiple-value-bind (tot cnt) (sub sxp 0 0)
      (/ tot cnt))))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me, unfortunately though I cant actually understand what the code is doing?

Comment: if you are using a local function, no sense passing and returning **tot** and **cnt**

Answer (score 1):

The following is similar to Le Petit Prince but without the local function returning multiple values. Basically this does depth-first walking and sums and counts at the leaves.

```
(defun nested-average2 (tree)
  (let ((sum 0)
        (cnt 0))
    (labels ((leaf-sum-cnt (branch)
               (cond ((null branch))          ; nothing
                     ((listp branch)          ; follow the branches
                      (leaf-sum-cnt (car branch))
                      (leaf-sum-cnt (cdr branch)))
                     (t (incf sum branch)     ; at a leaf
                        (incf cnt)))))
      (leaf-sum-cnt tree)
      (/ sum cnt))))
```

Of course this example is not very functional.  So if this is homework your professor may not like it.